# Argument of E. Fradkin on the mean-field theory of spin liquids

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-invariance

I have read the chapter 8 of *Field Theory of Condensed Matter Physics (2ed.)* by E. Fradkin a couple of times, but I still confused by his argument at some points. I hope you can help me with that.

After obtaining the Lagrangian, 
\begin{align}
L&= \sum_x c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x,t) (i\partial_t +\mu)c_{\alpha}(x,t) +\sum_x \varphi(x,t)(c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x)c_{\alpha}(x) -1) - \frac{2}{J}\sum_{x,j}|\chi_j(x)|^2 \\ \nonumber
&+ \sum_{x,j} c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x,t)\chi_j(x,t)c_{\alpha}(x+e_j,t) +c^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(x+e_j,t)\chi_j^*(x,t)c_{\alpha}(x,t),
\end{align}
when he considers the "local time-dependent gauge transformations", he arrives at $$S \rightarrow S -\sum_{x} (\phi(x,t\rightarrow +\infty) -\phi(x,t\rightarrow -\infty) ).$$

He continues to say that the invariance of $$\oint dt {\cal{A}_0}(x,t),\ \ ( {\cal{A}_0}(x,t) =\varphi(x,t)) $$ is required by the single occupancy at *every* site and at *all* times, and 
"[b]ecause of the gauge invariance, we need to impose the constraint of single
occupancy... only on the configuration space at some initial time surface,
$t = t_0$. The local gauge invariance implies that the spin configurations at an
arbitrary later time $t$ must still obey the same constraint; i.e. they are smooth
deformations of the initial configuration. For instance, we cannot try to fix the
gauge $A_0 = 0$ if only non-singular gauge transformations are allowed."

My question is: Why is $\oint dt {\cal{A}_0}(x,t)$ constant equivalent to the constraint on single occupation?